# Javascript: Moving Image using Mouse Events

Tags: javascript

I have seen other solutions, but they never worked for me. I am having trouble clicking an image, let it follow the cursor, and then release when I click again. So far I only have the image following the cursor when I click once, but don't know how to implement it to stop when I click again. This is what I have so far:

```
function moveImage(e) {
        var x = e.clientX-100;
        var y = e.clientY-100;

        document.getElementById("image").style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById("image").style.top = y + "px";

}   

function move(e) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragImage);
}

window.addEventListener("click", move, false);
```

How would I make the image stop following the cursor on a click?

Comment: "Dragging" means that the target sticks to the cursor when you push the mouse button down, and follows the cursor until you release the mouse button. This probably is not what you need?

Comment: True, I've edited the post. I want to be able to move the image, other than drag

Comment: You need two click listeners, one of them active at the time, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0rp5xmw2/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#div1").mousemove(function(e) 
 {
  var w = $(".image").css("width");
  w=parseFloat(w);
  w=w/2;
  
  var h = $(".image").css("height");
  h=parseFloat(h);
  h=h/2;
  
    $(".image").css({
   display:'block',
   left: e.pageX - w,
   top: e.pageY - h
  });
 });
 $("#div1").mouseout(function(e) 
 {
    $("#img1").css("display","none");
 });
});
```

```css
.image 
{
 display:none;
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img1" class="image" src="http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/59318bbeb74af41c008b605f/nuclear-bombs-trigger-a-strange-effect-that-can-fry-your-electronics--heres-how-it-works.jpg" />
<div id="div1" style="width:100%; height:500px; background-color:#09F">
```

is this what u want ?

im not good in js but this is jquery